# Docker: remove a setting when using multiple YAML files

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Using Docker Swarm, I keep all my "overrides" in a single `yml` file like so:

```
docker stack -c base.yml -c overrides.yml deploy myStack
```

If my `base.yml` file defines these deploy limits for `serviceA`:

```
serviceA:
  . . .
  deploy:
    resources:
      limits: {memory: 1024M}
      reservations: {memory: 1024M}
```

I can easily override in `overrides.yml`:

```
serviceA:
  deploy:
    resources:
      limits: {memory: 2048M}
      reservations: {memory: 2048M}
```

This way, my `base.yml` can change as new versions of the product are released, but any overrides are easily transported from the old to the new version.   However, what if I want to REMOVE or delete something defined in `base.yml`?  If I want to keep the `reservation`, but remove the `limits` definition by using a second `yml` file.  Is there any way to do this?  Currently, I am on yaml version 3.6.

These two options do not work.  This (is not parseable):

```
serviceA:
  deploy:
    resources:
      limits: {memory: }
      reservations: {memory: 2048M}
```

and this (uses the default defined in `base.yml`):

```
serviceA:
  deploy:
    resources:
      reservations: {memory: 2048M}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiple docker-compose files, the latter ones get merged into the former ones. That means: You cannot remove definitions, just modify existing ones or add new ones (see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3729). A [PR](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3939) to allow that was created and closed without ever being merged.

So all that leaves you with is to remove the `limits` definition from your `base.yml` and only have it in your `overrides.yml`.

Comment: Thank you - that info is not what I was hoping for, but exactly what I wanted confirmed!

Answer (score 0):

[fjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3599151/fjc) provided the actual answer to my question.  For the specific case I was interested in, I learned that if you 'override' and set the memory limit to zero (0), that is equivalent to not having set it at all.  Not a general workaround, but at least a workaround for this specific case.  For instance:

```
serviceA:
  deploy:
    resources:
      limits: { cpus: '0', memory: '0' }
```

would effectively not limit either the number of cpus or memory.